# ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in TicketsController#new

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models and controllers, one for Users and one for Tickets.

Each user can have many tickets. Each Admin user (denoted by `admin: true`) can have many tickets assigned to them.

Here are my associations:

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sender, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "id", inverse_of: :sent_tickets
  belongs_to :admin, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "id", inverse_of: :assigned_tickets

  .
  .
  .

end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  .
  .
  .

  has_many :sent_tickets, class_name: "Ticket", foreign_key: "sender", inverse_of: :sender, dependent: :nullify
  has_many :assigned_tickets, class_name: "Ticket", foreign_key: "assigned", inverse_of: :admin, dependent: :nullify

  .
  .
  .

end
```

However, anytime I try to run `@ticket = user.sent_tickets.build` (after running `user = User.first` in the Rails IRB, I get `ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in TicketsController#new: User(#number) expected, got Fixnum(#number)`

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. I renamed `sender` and `assigned` to `sender_id` and `assigned_id`. Then I rewrote my associations as such:

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :assigned, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :sender, class_name: "User"

  .
  .
  .

end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  .
  .
  .

  has_many :help_requests, foreign_key: "sender_id", class_name: "Ticket", dependent: :nullify
  has_many :sent_requests, through: :help_requests , source: :sender

  has_many :tickets, foreign_key: "assigned_id", dependent: :nullify
  has_many :assigned_tickets, through: :tickets, source: :assigned

  .
  .
  .

end
```